# c3p0 doen't open enough connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

I'm using Hibernate 3.4.0 GA and c3p0 0.9.0.4

The maxPoolSize property is set to 2000, but the maximun number of JDBC connections created is about 100, 110 (even when the program need more connections).

This is my configuration:
`<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">

    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />

    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />

    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2000"/>

    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="50"/>

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="50"/>

    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>

    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="60"/>

</bean>`

Any idea why?

Comment: How do you know it needs more connections? Have you taken a thread-dump and verified that you have 110 threads all hanging on a database operation? What is your thread-pool like, for that matter. Also, 2000 is pretty excessive when it comes to database connections. Are you sure you have a database instance that can serve that many concurrent queries?

Comment: I see threads that wait to excute a query to the database. I see in JavaMelody monitoring that there are 100 active connection to the database. In the mysql configuration file the max connection set to 2750

Comment: I'm very shore that 2000 connections on database, if you success to provide them, will not have effects as you want. You should see what's problem in your database so it needs so many connections at the same time. Probably neither SO has no so huge connection pool :)

Answer (score 2):

Number of connections is also limited on database server side. As far as I remember, for MySQL default max number of connections is 100.

See also http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/ for MySQL.

Comment: In the mysql configuration file the max connection set to 2750

Comment: @Blabla Are you sure it is applied correctly? If you run [show variables like "max_connections"], does it appear as you set in config?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set the connection pool parameters in your Hibernate configuration, as those particular parameters in c3p0.properties will be overwritten by Hibernate.

Try adding the following to your Hibernate properties configuration:

```
<property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>  
<property name="c3p0.max_size">2000</property> 
<property name="c3p0.min_size">50</property>
```

You can refer to the following link for more information: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool

Comment: Recommend you look at what the log output says when the connection pool is initialized. Should be printed by com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager and starts with "Initializing c3p0 pool..." It may be that some of your settings are not being picked up properly.

Comment: It's seems fine: driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 61f533, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> -1, initialPoolSize -> 50, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://[IP]:3306/macadb?characterEncoding=UTF-8, loginTimeout -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 60, **maxPoolSize -> 2000**, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 50, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null,

Comment: Then it seems your problem is not with the configuration - at least based on what I know.